# Background push notifications start working only after some time in iOS (firebase/aws/xamarin)

Tags: aws-lambda, push-notification, xamarin.ios, notifications, firebase-notifications

In my Xamarin app I need to receive background push notifications. These notifications are sent to firebase by an aws lambda. Firebase is already properly configured for iOS.
For testing I deploy the app on an ipad.
Initially the notifications works only in foreground, then, after waiting about ten minutes, it starts to work perfectly: no problem at all for notifications in foreground, background or when app is killed.
For "it works" I mean that *application:DidReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:* is called properly.
This situation occurs every time I deploy the app.
The same happens if I restart the device. After restarting I need to open the app and wait about ten minutes, otherwise no notification will come in background.

The payload:

```
{
    'to': ipadToken,
    'priority': 'high',
    'content_available': True,
    'data': {
        'title': 'Title Test',
        'body': 'Body Test'
    }
}
```

It is a very bizarre situation for me, can it be related to apns or ios in any way?
Any ideas to solve?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you tell us which plugin are you using ? Have you checked the issue list to see if there is any similar problem ?

Comment: I use the _Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging_. I also added to the project the _GoogleService-Info.plist_ file that I downloaded from Firebase. Then I wrote the code using _Xamarin.iOS_ libraries, so it would be like it's native code I suppose.